# how to improve the code commit process - Heroku

Tags: heroku, devops, commit, heroku-pipelines

Currently, our Heroku Pipeline is review -> staging -> production.

We will do all the tasks, then create PR and merge to review app, then create the same PR (done mainly by cherry-picking), then make the PR and merge to stage, and then finally, we will promote to the production app.

But we will not do the Heroku promotion between the review and stage because we cannot make all the tasks from review to stage; most of them are POCs so they will sit only in the review app.

The main problem is when we create the PR for the stage, and we will cherry-pick the commit, which may include the other code that is not supposed to go to the stage, making commit conflicts; then we will remove the conflicts; we may get some confusion; many times, those codes went live; that we have already experienced, and that caused issues.

So how can we resolve this issue or any standard way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mater how many different pipelines you implement if you are just going to cherry-pick the pr's you want.

Before pushing to review the programmers should make sure all the code is **pulled** so the possible conflicts are resolved by the programmer before pushing new code to the review branch.

If you know all the programmers made sure to pull before push you know there will be no more conflicts moving forward and you should be able to cherry-pick the commits you want to go to staging.

Staging should be an environment as close to production so you can have a final check if everything works. Staging -> Production should just be a one to one merge.